# JSON Schema for tree structure

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have to build tree like structure of Json data.Each node has an id (an integer, required), a label (a string, optional), and an array of child nodes (optional). Can you help me how to write JSON schema for this Json data. I need to set Id as required in child node as well.

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Label": "A",
    "Child": [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Label": "B",
            "Child": [
                {
                    "Id": 5,
                    "Label": "E"
                }, {
                    "Id": 6,
                    "Label": "E"
                }, {
                    "Id": 7,
                    "Label": "E"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "Id": 3,
            "Label": "C"
        }, {
            "Id": 4,
            "Label": "D",
            "Child": [
                {
                    "Id": 8,
                    "Label": "H"
                }, {
                    "Id": 9,
                    "Label": "I"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A schema for this structure only needs a definition of a node and a reference to that node. The property `Children` (renamed from `Child`) references the `node` as well.

Here's the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/node",
  "definitions": {
    "node": {
      "properties": {
        "Id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Label": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```