# Recursive search function for Javascript object with arrays of nested objects

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, recursion

I have to create a javascript function to do a recursive search on an object and get the label name for the given ID.

I tried with the below code but it returns `undefined` for any id. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
function GetLabel(data, Id) {
  var i,
    currentChild,
    result;

  if (Id == data.Id) {
    return data['Label'];
  } else {
    for (field in data) {
      if (typeof(data[field]) == "object") {
        result = GetLabel(data[field], Id);
        if (result != "") return result;
      }

      if (data[field] == Id) {
        result = data['Label'];
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your json too

Comment: Assuming your ids are unique there are two approaches. If you will be doing this search multiple times it's best to flatten your nested structure into a hash table like a big object with properties of "id" and and you just look up like table[id] every time you need to make search. Or if you will not be doing many searches a recursive method can also be implemented for this job, which will run through the whole tree like a crazy dog every time you search for something.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the data structure of this question: [JSON Schema for tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150668/json-schema-for-tree-structure)

This proposal uses an a function for recursive call and some changes, basically for the iteration of `child`, which is an array instead of an object, which may supposed to be.

After a check if `child` is an array, [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) helps iterating and stops if the wanted `id` is found.

I suggest to use a common style guide for naming convention and write all properties in small letters, as well as functions which may not be used as constructor.

```js
function getLabel(data, id) {
    var result;
    if (id === data.id) {
        return data.label;
    }
    Array.isArray(data.child) && data.child.some(function (a) {
        result = getLabel(a, id);
        if (result) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var tree = { id: 1, label: "A", child: [{ id: 2, label: "B", child: [{ id: 5, label: "E" }, { id: 6, label: "F" }, { id: 7, label: "G" }] }, { id: 3, label: "C" }, { id: 4, label: "D", child: [{ id: 8, label: "H" }, { id: 9, label: "I" }] }] },
    i;

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    document.write(getLabel(tree, i) + '<br>');
}
```