# How to create a tree structure representation in JSON?

Tags: json

I am new in JSON and I would like to understand how to create a JSON representation of a tree like this one: [image: tree]

where each node has id (integer required), label (string, optional) and an array of childs node (optional).

Any suggestion is welcome, I really do not know where to start

Comment: I don't know where to start explaining because all of this seems blatantly obvious. Do you know how to represent a single-node tree? E.g. one consisting only of the node with id 5.

Comment: @melpomene how for example to set required a field?

Comment: You don't. JSON is a raw data serialization format, not a schema description.

Comment: what about this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150668/json-schema-for-tree-structure @melpomene

Comment: That's about JSON Schema, not JSON.

Answer (score 3):

What about this? 
Did the child have to be reused?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "A",
    "child": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "B",
            "child": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "label": "E",
                    "child": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "label": "F",
                    "child": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "label": "G",
                    "child": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "C",
            "child": []
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "label": "D",
            "child": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "label": "H",
                    "child": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "label": "I",
                    "child": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How to set required a field?

Comment: You didn't mention webgraphviz in your requirements. Please edit your question and add more details

Comment: Sorry about that, forget webgraphviz, I do not need it

Comment: So what is wrong with the solution? Is it what you want?

Comment: what about this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150668/json-schema-for-tree-structure